# How to upload objects to Firebase Storage using Postman for testing?

Tags: php, android, ios

How to upload images to Firebase cloud storage using postman for testing purposes.

Comment: I have tried image upload using multi-part following this post. 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here we will try to upload images to Firebase Storage using **simple upload** request in the **Google Cloud Storage JSON API**.

1) You need to create a project at FireBase console to begin. You can create a project at FireBase console using the link **https://console.firebase.google.com/?authuser=0**

2) Go to Console and navigate to option stating Storage. If project creation was correct you will get a storage created at default bucket such as **imageupload.appspot.com** in my case.

3) Now we need the url were we post our image using postman. You can get the url by uploading an image to your storage. Hence upload the image.

[image]

click on File location you will get the url of uploaded image. eg:

**http://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/imageupload.appspot.com/o/IMG-20170630-WA0003.jpg?alt=media&token=f59a9a31-65d7-4e5b-88cf-fc117deacc21** where our required url for posting image is: **http://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/imageupload.appspot.com/o**

4) Now change the Rules at Firebase Storage:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

This will allow a public access to your url. You can read more about it at **http://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start**

6) **Sending a simple upload request:**
To use simple upload, create a **POST** request to the method's /upload URI.

6-a) Add the query parameter **uploadType=media**.

For example, for a bucket named myBucket:

**POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/imageupload.appspot.com/o?uploadType=media**

6-b) Add a name query parameter to identify which resource the upload is associated with.

For example, to specify that an object's name is myObject:

**POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/imageupload.appspot.com/o?uploadType=media&name=myObject**

6-c) Add the file's data to the request body.

6-d) set **contentType: image/png** as I am uploading a png image from postman.

6-e) Send the request.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Amazing tutorial (note that it also work with Form data). Thanks a lot!